# How to get top-down hierarchy of a field in Kubernetes resource yaml structure?

Tags: kubernetes, yaml

I want to know what will be the appropriate position of a field in the resource yaml file (say e.g. `capabilities` field in a `pod` yaml file).

I can use `kubectl explain pod.spec --recursive | less` and then *search* for `capabilities` and then scroll up to see who is the parent field of `capabilities` field and so on.

Is there a *simpler* way to know the hierarchy or parents of field?

I want to see hierarchical output something like this without having to scroll up and figure out manually:

`pod > spec > containers > securityContext > capabilities`

Answer (score 1):

I hose this will be helpful,
you can use the `yq` to output your file in many ways.

- Get directly what you desire

```
cat my-yaml-file.yaml | yq e '.spec.template.spec.containers'
```

- The `-f` will output it in a JSON Format.

```
cat my-yaml-file.yaml | yq e -j '.spec.template.spec.containers'
```

- Delete everything after a specific point :

```
cat my-yaml-file.yaml | yq e -j 'del(.spec.template.spec.containers)'
```